# How to create an altcoin

Tags: litecoin, altcoin

I'd like to create a Litecoin fork. This is purely for educational purposes. Any tips on how to get started? I've googled for guides online but I can't find any good ones. Info is scattered all over the place. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are or there were sites where you could input a coin name, logo and other parameters and download a built app for your custom coin, without any knowledge of programming. But once the question states that's for educational purposes, I'll suggest the following:

1. Download the Litecoin sources and build it from scratch. Refer to the Litecoin project tutorials for details of how to do that for your operating system.
2. Run it to make sure you got everything right.
3. Make some random changes to the source and build and run it again to see the effects.
4. Make changes to the relevant bits of the source, like the name of the coin, logo, app name, texts shown to the user, genesis block id or whatever else is necessary to make a different coin. Build and run it again.

Comment: can you share those websites?

Comment: I don't remember what ones I saw, it was years ago, but it was like this: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=704105.0